# Selecting two items from different lists at the same time via multi-touch in WP8.

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

How can i select two items at the same time from two different longlistselector controls. I am developing an application which requires to select one item from two different list at the same time.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="inputList" ItemSource="{Binding InputListItems}" >
```

Comment: What do you mean by selecting one item from two lists? Do you want to synchronize two lists? Is the item you want to select present in both lists?

Comment: Can't you just handle selection change event and select item in another list box?

Comment: It's FindTheMatch Game where i need to select identical items from two different list at the same time and if items are identical...i would remove those items from the lists.

Comment: You mean like multi touching? Or do you need successive touches?

Comment: Yes exactly Multi-touch, How can i achieve that in WP programming ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple controls and you want to handle multi touch events, you will have to do it manually. Use `Touch.FrameReported` to extract touch points, find out which controls are underneath each touch point and then act on it.

See this example here:  [How to build a multi-touch control for Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_build_a_multi-touch_control_for_Windows_Phone).